# How to get the output of `find` as a space separated string?

Tags: bash, find

I would like to list all the filenames inside a directory as a single argument string line that uses the <kbd>Space</kbd> character as separator.

Let's consider this directory:

```
/project
├─ foo bar.c
├─ bar is not baz.c
├─ you"are"doomed
└─ baz.c
```

An output to my problem would be:

```
. "./bar is not baz.c" ./baz.c "./foo bar.c" 'you"are"doomed'
```

Or

```
. foo\ bar.c bar\ is\ not\ baz.c baz.c you\"are\"doomed
```

Obviously it doesn't work with the null character `\0` because this char cannot be processed on the arguments line:

```
find . -print0

. foo bar.c\0bar is not baz.c\0baz.c\0you"are"doomed
```

My goal is to pass these files to another program in this way

```
program `find . | magic` 

. foo\ bar.c bar\ is\ not\ baz.c baz.c you\"are\"doomed
```

**EDIT (3 years later)**

As identified by [devsolar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60281/devsolar) my question was a kind of a XY problem. His solution allows to pass the list of files to a program. However it does not answer the initial question completely.

The reason why I need an argument *string* is that I want to avoid to execute my `program` for each file found because it is too slow (especially on [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin)).

Using `xargs` does not help either because it cannot escape all the chars. The closest to the solution I have been to is with this oneliner:

```
find . -print0 | perl -e 'local $/="\0";print join(" ",map{s/(?=["'"'"' ])/\\/gr}<STDIN>);'

. ./bar\ is\ not\ baz.c ./baz.c ./foo\ bar.c ./haha\"haha
```

Comment: What if the file name contains a space?

Comment: Very good point ! I guess I should escape it in quotes then !

Comment: Do you need all of the files in subdirectories too, or would a glob  `program *` be sufficient?

Comment: Instead of escaping is better to use the `-print0`. Remember: the ` ` (one space) and/or `\n` (one newline) are valid filenames... And the escaping not really helps for filenames containing `\n` if you want process them in the pipe...

Comment: Replacing line feeds with spaces for this purpose is both unnecessary and ineffectual. Adding quotes around it like you show doesn't work. DevSolar shows how to correctly pass find output to a command as parameters.

Comment: I believe you have explained in your edit why it's not (always) a XY problem.

Comment: Note that my answer, right from the very start, also includes an answer that starts your `program` for a list of files as well. Actually, that is what I answered *first* before *also* showing a solution that starts `program` once per file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Do

```
find . -exec program {} +
```

for calling `program` with a list of filenames as parameter. If *lots* of files are found, there might be more than one call to `program` to avoid too-long command line.

Do

```
find . -exec program {} \;
```

to call `program` for *each* file found.

Yes, this *does* work correctly with spaces in filenames.

Comment: In `find . -exec program {} +` how to correctly strip `./` from `find` results? The reason of stripping `./` is possible exceeding of `ARG_MAX`.

Comment: @pmor I am not sure what you mean by "stripping `./`". Exclusing the contents of the current directory? That would be done by adding `-mindepth 2`. However, `+` should never exceed the number of possible arguments. ("If *lots* of files are found, there might be more than one call to `program` to avoid too-long command line.")

Comment: The `find . -type f ` outputs `./file` instead of `file`. Some people consider this as an issue: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331696/334715), [2](https://serverfault.com/q/354403/563232). Therefore, one solution is to strip the `./` via, for example, `| sed 's|^./||'`. However, how to correctly strip `./` in case of `find . -exec program {} +`?

Comment: @pmor *What for*? The `./` just makes sure that whatever command you `-exec` "knows" that `{}` is referring to a file instead of e.g. a command, or alias. Seriously, I don't see any reason to bother about it. If you want to get a textual list of the files found, you can `-printf "%P\n"`. But for `-exec`, again, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Re: "What for?": to increase the probability that the max. length of arguments will not exceed `ARG_MAX`. Example: 1000 arguments with `./` each will lead to +2000 extra (?) characters.

Comment: @pmor You *have* read the part where I explained that `{} +` will split into multiple invocations of the command then? I doubt that jumping through hoops to get the `./` removed from every entry outweighs the performance gained by perhaps saving one additional command invocation on average.

Comment: Re: "there might be more than one call to `program` to avoid too-long command line": consider elaborating (by perhaps updating the answer?).

Comment: @pmor It's *right there in the answer*. "If lots of files are found, there might be more than one call to program to avoid too-long command line." Source for this information: `man find` on `{} +` / `man xargs` (which is referenced by `man find`).

Comment: Is this _information_ a quote from `man find` or `man xargs`? Neither in `man find` nor in `man xargs` I see this quote. In `man find` just below `-exec command {} +` I see "the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files". Is this a right information? Also: what if one needs only one invocation of the program and "returns a non‐zero exit status" if this cannot be done (e.g. due to exceeding of `ARG_MAX`)?

Comment: @pmor How about you post a separate question if you are confused about the functionality of `find ... {} +` and `xargs` with regards to exceeding `ARG_MAX`? This back-and-forth has been going on for a while now, and I start getting a feeling of pointless pointification here.

Answer (score 16):

if you can use other commands, probably

```
find . | paste -sd " "
```

does what you need.

On OS X, another argument is needed:

```
find . | paste -sd " " -
```

Answer (score 10):

All you need to do to convert a list separated by linebreaks into one separated by spaces is to do an echo on them like this:

```
echo $(find)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar need to constuct a CSV string of dirnames that would be passed to an `--exclude=` param of `snyk monitor`.  I ended up with this invocation (Alpine linux 3.17, so uses BusyBox find, not GNU find):

```
snyk monitor --all-projects --exclude=$(find * -type d \( -name "*.UnitTests" -o -name "*.SystemTests" \) -exec printf '%s,' {} +)
```

The output of `find` is passed using `-exec` to `printf`. Each result is passed as `{}`.  `"%s,"` formats each item with a comma.  You could have `"%s "`.

I use `find *` rather than `find .` as I did not want each dir name preceeded with a `./`

Only downside of this approach is that the *last* item also includes a `,` in the output string

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you:

```
$ find -type f .| tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 YOUR_PROGRAM
```

1. `find . -type f`: gets all files From the current directory down
2. `tr '\n' '\0'`: translates the output of find to a null separated list.
3. `xargs -0 YOUR_PROGRAM` passes that list to your program using a null delimiter instead of the default space delimiter in order to handle file names with spaces.

Comment: This would not work with file names with spaces in it

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25759964)

Answer (score -2):

I finally found a good solution:

```
find . | awk '{printf "%s ", $0}'
```

Comment: Why is this more convenient than what you had?

Comment: Because `paste -sd` doesn't work with `cleartool find` and `cleartool find -exec` is too slow. So this solution works find to me.